# Adding Indexes to improve performance

Tags: sql, oracle10g, sql-execution-plan

I have a query which is taking around  4 hrs to execute. I need to add indexes to improve the performance. Please suggest where I can add the indexes for the explain plan below: Also please suggest how to add the indexes in the query.

## Query:

```
SELECT 
 TO_CHAR(GREATEST(cns.start_date, NVL(cvs.start_date,'01-JAN-1900'), NVL(cvc.start_date,'01-JAN-1900')),'DD-MON-RRRR HH24:MI:SS')  START_DATE, 
 TO_CHAR(LEAST(cns.end_date, NVL(cvs.end_date,'31-DEC-3999'), NVL(cvc.end_date,'31-DEC-3999')) ,'DD-MON-RRRR HH24:MI:SS') END_DATE, 
 DECODE(cns.STATUS,'CI','I','CU','I','QI','I','QU','I') STATUS,  
 CNS_CST_SER_BIT, 
 CNS_IDENT,
 cns_nst_code  CNS_NST_CODE, 

 (SELECT DISTINCT NST_IDENT FROM number_string_type NST 
 WHERE nst_code = cns.cns_nst_code 
 AND nvl(NST.end_date,'31-DEC-3999') > TO_DATE(:V_From_Date,'DD-MON-RRRR HH24:MI:SS')  
 AND GREATEST(NST.start_date,cns.start_date, NVL(cvs.start_date,'01-JAN-1900'), NVL(cvc.start_date,'01-JAN-1900')) 
 <  LEAST(NST.end_date,cns.end_date, NVL(cvs.end_date,'31-DEC-3999'), NVL(cvc.end_date,'31-DEC-3999')) )

 NST_IDENT, 
 CNS_DESC,  
 CNS_CNT_IDENT,
 CNS_SYS_BIT,  
 CNS_CST_CODE, 

 (SELECT DISTINCT  cst_ident FROM charge_structure CST
 WHERE cst_code = cns.cns_cst_code  
 AND nvl(CST.end_date,'31-DEC-3999') > TO_DATE(:V_From_Date,'DD-MON-RRRR HH24:MI:SS')
 AND GREATEST(CST.start_date,cns.start_date, NVL(cvs.start_date,'01-JAN-1900'), NVL(cvc.start_date,'01-JAN-1900'))
 < LEAST(CST.end_date,cns.end_date, NVL(cvs.end_date,'31-DEC-3999'), NVL(cvc.end_date,'31-DEC-3999')) ) 
 CST_IDENT, 
 CNS_FREE, 
 CNS_EXC_1141, 
 CNS_CRY_CODE, 
 (SELECT DISTINCT Cry_IDENT FROM country CRY 
 WHERE cns.cns_cry_code = cry_code 
 AND nvl(CRY.end_date,'31-DEC-3999') > TO_DATE(:V_From_Date,'DD-MON-RRRR HH24:MI:SS')  
 AND GREATEST(CRY.start_date,cns.start_date, NVL(cvs.start_date,'01-JAN-1900'), NVL(cvc.start_date,'01-JAN-1900'))
 < LEAST(CRY.end_date,cns.end_date, NVL(cvs.end_date,'31-DEC-3999'), NVL(cvc.end_date,'31-DEC-3999')) ) 
 CRY_IDENT,  
 CNS_TEL_CODE , 
 (SELECT DISTINCT TEL_IDENT FROM TELEPHONY_ADMINISTRATION TEL
 WHERE cns.cns_tel_code = tel_code  
 AND nvl(TEL.end_date,'31-DEC-3999') > TO_DATE(:V_From_Date,'DD-MON-RRRR HH24:MI:SS')
 AND GREATEST(TEL.start_date,cns.start_date, NVL(cvs.start_date,'01-JAN-1900'), NVL(cvc.start_date,'01-JAN-1900'))
 < LEAST(TEL.end_date,cns.end_date, NVL(cvs.end_date,'31-DEC-3999'), NVL(cvc.end_date,'31-DEC-3999'))) 
 TEL_IDENT, 
 CNS_ADD_DIGITS,
 CNS_TIMEOUT, 
 CNS_CVS_CODE,
 CVS_DESC,
 CNS_CVC_CODE, 
 CVC_DESC, 
 CNS_DIGITAL_ONLY,
 CNS_DST_CODE,
 (SELECT DISTINCT DST_IDENT FROM district DST 
 WHERE cns.cns_dst_code = dst_code  AND nvl(DST.end_date,'31-DEC-3999') > TO_DATE(:V_From_Date,'DD-MON-RRRR HH24:MI:SS') 
 AND GREATEST(DST.start_date,cns.start_date, NVL(cvs.start_date,'01-JAN-1900'),  NVL(cvc.start_date,'01-JAN-1900'))
 < LEAST(DST.end_date,cns.end_date,  NVL(cvs.end_date,'31-DEC-3999'),  NVL(cvc.end_date,'31-DEC-3999')))
 DST_IDENT, 
 CNS_BEFORE_AFTER, 
 CNS_CODE_CHANGE_RULE,
 CNS_CTY_CODE, 
 (SELECT DISTINCT CTY_IDENT FROM call_type CTY 
 WHERE cns.cns_cty_code = cty_code  
 AND nvl(CTY.end_date,'31-DEC-3999') > TO_DATE(:V_From_Date,'DD-MON-RRRR HH24:MI:SS') 
 AND GREATEST(CTY.start_date,cns.start_date, NVL(cvs.start_date,'01-JAN-1900'),  NVL(cvc.start_date,'01-JAN-1900'))
 < LEAST(CTY.end_date,cns.end_date, NVL(cvs.end_date,'31-DEC-3999'),  NVL(cvc.end_date,'31-DEC-3999'))) 
 CTY_IDENT, 
 CNS_NCRF,  
 CNS_OLO_CODE, 
 (SELECT DISTINCT OLO_IDENT FROM other_licensed_operator OLO
 WHERE cns.cns_olo_code = olo_code 
 AND nvl(OLO.end_date,'31-DEC-3999') > TO_DATE(:V_From_Date,'DD-MON-RRRR HH24:MI:SS')  
 AND GREATEST(OLO.start_date,cns.start_date, NVL(cvs.start_date,'01-JAN-1900'), NVL(cvc.start_date,'01-JAN-1900'))
 < LEAST(OLO.end_date,cns.end_date, NVL(cvs.end_date,'31-DEC-3999'), NVL(cvc.end_date,'31-DEC-3999'))) 
 OLO_IDENT, 
 CNS_WCC_CODE,  
 CNS_OLO_LOPID, 
 CNS_LUS_BAR_FLAG   FROM cns cns, cns_valid_status cvs, cns_valid_category cvc  
 WHERE cns.cns_cvs_code = cvs_code(+)  index1
 AND cns.cns_cvc_code = cvc_code(+) 
 and greatest(cns.start_date, nvl(cvs.start_date,'01-JAN-1900'), nvl(cvc.start_date,'01-JAN-1900')) 
 < least(cns.end_date,nvl(cvs.end_date,'31-DEC-3999'), nvl(cvc.end_date,'31-DEC-3999'))  
 and nvl(cns.end_date,'31-DEC-3999') > TO_DATE(:V_From_Date,'DD-MON-RRRR HH24:MI:SS')  
 order by cns.cns_ident,1,2; 

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                       | Name                     | Rows  | Bytes |TempSpc| Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                |                          |       |       |       |  4855 (100)|          |
|   1 |  HASH UNIQUE                    |                          |     1 |    25 |       |     3  (34)| 00:00:01 |
|   2 |   MAT_VIEW ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| NUMBER_STRING_TYPE       |     1 |    25 |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   3 |    INDEX RANGE SCAN             | INST_2                   |     1 |       |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   4 |  HASH UNIQUE                    |                          |     1 |    27 |       |     4  (25)| 00:00:01 |
|   5 |   MAT_VIEW ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| CHARGE_STRUCTURE         |     1 |    27 |       |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   6 |    INDEX RANGE SCAN             | ICST_1                   |     2 |       |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   7 |  HASH UNIQUE                    |                          |     1 |    25 |       |     3  (34)| 00:00:01 |
|   8 |   MAT_VIEW ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| COUNTRY                  |     1 |    25 |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   9 |    INDEX RANGE SCAN             | ICRY_1                   |     1 |       |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  10 |  HASH UNIQUE                    |                          |     1 |    33 |       |     3  (34)| 00:00:01 |
|  11 |   MAT_VIEW ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| TELEPHONY_ADMINISTRATION |     1 |    33 |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  12 |    INDEX RANGE SCAN             | ITEL_2                   |     1 |       |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  13 |  HASH UNIQUE                    |                          |     1 |    23 |       |     3  (34)| 00:00:01 |
|  14 |   MAT_VIEW ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| DISTRICT                 |     1 |    23 |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  15 |    INDEX RANGE SCAN             | IDST_1                   |     1 |       |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  16 |  HASH UNIQUE                    |                          |     1 |    24 |       |     3  (34)| 00:00:01 |
|  17 |   MAT_VIEW ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| CALL_TYPE                |     1 |    24 |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  18 |    INDEX RANGE SCAN             | ICTY_1                   |     1 |       |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  19 |  HASH UNIQUE                    |                          |     1 |    27 |       |     4  (25)| 00:00:01 |
|  20 |   MAT_VIEW ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| OTHER_LICENSED_OPERATOR  |     1 |    27 |       |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  21 |    INDEX RANGE SCAN             | IOLO_1                   |     2 |       |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  22 |  SORT ORDER BY                  |                          | 35110 |  6411K|    13M|  4855   (2)| 00:00:59 |
|  23 |   FILTER                        |                          |       |       |       |            |          |
|  24 |    HASH JOIN RIGHT OUTER        |                          | 35110 |  6411K|       |  3418   (2)| 00:00:42 |
|  25 |     MAT_VIEW ACCESS FULL        | CNS_VALID_STATUS         |     5 |   140 |       |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  26 |     HASH JOIN RIGHT OUTER       |                          | 35110 |  5451K|       |  3414   (2)| 00:00:41 |
|  27 |      MAT_VIEW ACCESS FULL       | CNS_VALID_CATEGORY       |     4 |   144 |       |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  28 |      MAT_VIEW ACCESS FULL       | CNS                      | 35110 |  4217K|       |  3411   (2)| 00:00:41 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: No query, no version, no schema, and some raw dump of an execution plan? No chance

Comment: Please ad: query, RDBS, data

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, every object in this query is in a remote database accessed by the database link "live".  Assuming that you are showing the local query plan, it appears that Oracle is pulling all the data for all those objects locally to do the joins.  The query plan seems to believe that this will take roughly a second.  The fact that it's taking 4 hours strongly implies that the statistics in the remote database are wildly incorrect.  Can you create a view in the remote database that performs this join?  If so, that would likely force the join to be done remotely.

Comment: Not being an Oracle person, I immediately thought of the performance issues correlated subqueries give you (at least in SQLServer) from this link, it appears they may be a problem in Oracle as well. http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_tuning_sql_subqueries.htm

Comment: I am executing the query from the same database(live). However we can run it remotely too. Can you please suggest the performance improvement methods for this query?

Answer (score 0):

Prompted by Justin's observation in the comments, you might investigate using the DRIVING_SITE hint to get the query executed in the remote database.

http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements006.htm#BABEGIJC

Comment: I am executing the query from the same database(live). However we can run it remotely too. Can you please suggest the performance improvement methods for this query?

Comment: I'd suggest that you look into event tracing, which will give you an exact breakdown of what event in the database is causing the query to run for four hours.